# Tornado: Absolute path of static handler

Tags: tornado

I set the static path in the settings dictionary as such:

```
 settings = {
              "static_path": "static",
              # rest of settings
            }
```

I need to get the static path in the application so I use:

```
self.application.settings["static_path"]
```

However this doesn't give the absolute path of the directory. Is there a way to get the absolute path of this directory without using the os library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use classmethod [`StaticFileHandler.get_absolute_path`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.StaticFileHandler.get_absolute_path). This is the recommended way, since it's used all over in `StaticFileHandler` and could be overridden to change interaction with filesystem. Nonetheless the default implementation is just [`os.path.abspath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath).

Comment: Thanks kwarunek I have to say I don't really understand this method. It accepts a root and a path and mentions the root is the static_path set in the settings. However you still have to pass this variable. What's the point of passing the variable and not having it as an optional? i am currently using the os.getcwd()

Comment: This method is a **classmethod**, it doesn't have context of handler object, application, so it requires the `root`, in fact internally `StaticFileHandler` object passes to this method the same `application.settings['static_path']`.

Comment: Yes it makes sense just realised it was a classmethod ok this is cool! Thanks mate!!

Comment: The reason it is classmethod is that `StaticFileHandler` object is created on every request, more over you can have many different StaticFileHandler with different static_path

Comment: I see ok makes sense ;)